# How to generate sequence of numbers matching a pattern?

Tags: algorithm, pattern-matching, generator, sequence

I need to generate a sequence of all numbers, matching a pattern in a certain number range. For example:

- range start: 1
- range end: 100
- pattern: *9* (i.e. in regexp `[0-9]*9[0-9]*`)
- expected result: [9, 19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89, 90, ..., 99]

Of course I could use a brute-force approach where I loop through all numbers of the range and test each number against the pattern. Here an example implementation done in Python:

```python
def brute_force(start, end, limit, pattern):
    if start < pattern:
        start = pattern
    if pattern > end:
        return []

    pattern_str = str(pattern)        
    generator = (n for n in range(start, end) if pattern_str in str(n))
    return list(next(generator) for _ in range(limit))
```

Unfortunately, the range is quite large (10^7 numbers) and I have to do that frequently in my program with changing patterns. Therefore, I need a more efficient approach.

It is important to note that I need to have a sorted list and that I often only need the X first matching numbers (see limit parameter in example above).

I guess there is some kind of standard algorithm for this kind of problem, but I don't know what to search for. Any ideas?

Comment: What's the format of the pattern? Does * mean 0 or 1 numbers? Or 0 or more?

Comment: * means any kind of number, also multiple numbers, but also no numbers. So 9, 19, 91, 191, 459, 945, 45945, etc. are all matching the pattern \*9\*.

Comment: Why you didn't list numbers 90, 91, 92, ..., 98 which seem to match your pattern?

Comment: @Donkey good point, I forgot. Updated question.

Comment: Is your pattern always *Digit*? or it will be any pattern like *912*23*4?

Comment: The * can only be given at the start or beginning, not in-between. So \*digits, digits\*, and \*digits\*.

Comment: Is it always * digit+ * or is it possible to have digit+ * or * digit+? (Where digit+ means 1 or more digits.)

Comment: How can there be 10^7 numbers between 1 and 100 ??

Comment: @YvesDaoust He is illustrating the idea...that's just an example...

Comment: @YvesDaoust In the question, I gave an example, which is simplified. In reality, range end is not 100, but 10.000.000.

Comment: Your description of the pattern is ambiguous. Can you give rigorous regexp syntax ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust I believe in regular expressions it would be: `[0-9]*9[0-9]*`

Comment: Ok, so any number having at least one nine.

Comment: Yes, but keep in mind that in reality the pattern will be something like \*1234567\* in a range of 10^7 numbers.

Comment: What do you mean with \*1234567\* ??? I completely don't understand your last remark. Please use a regexpr and make it fully general.

Comment: Is the start of the range always 1?

Comment: @tobias_k No, it is a parameter. The only constrain is that it must be smaller than range end. So it could also be 100.000 and range end 10.000.000 and pattern \*1234567\*.

Comment: What about negative or floating point numbers?

Comment: @tobias_k Only integers, no floating point numbers. In my case, it won't be a negative number, but I believe a valid algorithm would be able to handle negative numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a general solution that generates numbers up to a fixed size matching `*(pat)*` where `pat` is any sequence of digits.

It generates the numbers in increasing order, without duplicates. Because it's a generator, one can easily use it to generate the first few results without generating the entire list. (See the last example below).

```
def numbers(pat, k, matched=1):
    if (matched >> len(pat)) & 1:
        for x in xrange(10 ** k):
            yield x
        return
    if not ((matched << k) >> len(pat)):
        return
    for d in xrange(10):
        nm = 1
        for i, pd in enumerate(pat):
            if pd == str(d) and (matched >> i) & 1:
                nm |= 1 << (i+1)
        for n in numbers(pat, k - 1, nm):
            yield 10 ** (k - 1) * d + n
```

It works by recording how much of `pat` has been matched so far. To avoid backtracking when `pat` has been partially matched and the next digit does not match, it keeps a bitmap of all possible partial matches so far, in much the same way that a (non-backtracking) regexp matcher does.

Here's some test code, that checks it against the slow but obviously correct implementation.

```
def numbers_slow(pat, k):
    for i in xrange(10 ** k):
        if pat in str(i):
            yield i

test_cases = [
    ('9', 3),
    ('9', 4),
    ('123', 4),
    ('22', 4),
]
for pat, k in test_cases:
    got = list(numbers(pat, k))
    want = list(numbers_slow(pat, k))
    if got != want:
        print 'numbers(%s, %d) = %s, want %s' % (pat, k, got, want)
```

And here's the example given in the question:

```
print list(numbers('9', 3))

[9, 19, 29, 39, 49, 59, 69, 79, 89, 90, 91, 92, 93, 94, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 109,
119, 129, 139, 149, 159, 169, 179, 189, 190, 191, 192, 193, 194, 195, 196, 197,
198, 199, 209, 219, 229, 239, 249, 259, 269, 279, 289, 290, 291, 292, 293, 294,
295, 296, 297, 298, 299, 309, 319, 329, 339, 349, 359, 369, 379, 389, 390, 391,
392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 409, 419, 429, 439, 449, 459, 469, 479,
489, 490, 491, 492, 493, 494, 495, 496, 497, 498, 499, 509, 519, 529, 539, 549,
559, 569, 579, 589, 590, 591, 592, 593, 594, 595, 596, 597, 598, 599, 609, 619,
629, 639, 649, 659, 669, 679, 689, 690, 691, 692, 693, 694, 695, 696, 697, 698,
699, 709, 719, 729, 739, 749, 759, 769, 779, 789, 790, 791, 792, 793, 794, 795,
796, 797, 798, 799, 809, 819, 829, 839, 849, 859, 869, 879, 889, 890, 891, 892,
893, 894, 895, 896, 897, 898, 899, 900, 901, 902, 903, 904, 905, 906, 907, 908,
909, 910, 911, 912, 913, 914, 915, 916, 917, 918, 919, 920, 921, 922, 923, 924,
925, 926, 927, 928, 929, 930, 931, 932, 933, 934, 935, 936, 937, 938, 939, 940,
941, 942, 943, 944, 945, 946, 947, 948, 949, 950, 951, 952, 953, 954, 955, 956,
957, 958, 959, 960, 961, 962, 963, 964, 965, 966, 967, 968, 969, 970, 971, 972,
973, 974, 975, 976, 977, 978, 979, 980, 981, 982, 983, 984, 985, 986, 987, 988,
989, 990, 991, 992, 993, 994, 995, 996, 997, 998, 999]
```

Here's a less easy case:

```
print list(numbers('11', 3))

[11, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118, 119, 211, 311, 411, 511, 611,
711, 811, 911]
```

And a case that shows the method is efficient even for large numbers of digits:

```
print list(numbers('121212121', 10))

[121212121, 1121212121, 1212121210, 1212121211, 1212121212, 1212121213,
1212121214, 1212121215, 1212121216, 1212121217, 1212121218, 1212121219,
2121212121, 3121212121, 4121212121, 5121212121, 6121212121, 7121212121,
8121212121, 9121212121]
```

And to demonstrate the ability to limit the generated results, here's the first 21 numbers up to 20 digits long that contain '100000':

```
print itertools.islice(numbers('100000', 20), 21)

[100000, 1000000, 1000001, 1000002, 1000003, 1000004, 1000005, 1000006, 1000007,
1000008, 1000009, 1100000, 2100000, 3100000, 4100000, 5100000, 6100000, 7100000,
8100000, 9100000, 10000000]
```

Comment: Cool, man, +1. Now you've inspired me to try a "next lexicographic" :) If you are at all inclined, please poke some holes in it.

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful solution. It took me some time to understand, but now I think I got it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since you only need the first `x` numbers, lets look at it from the point of view of the number of the digits.

One digit is easy.
For two digits, get all options for the additional digits needed (8 possibilities). Then, working from the smallest to the largest, get the combination with the smallest value. Then iterate again with the combination with the bigger value.
The case for three digits or more is the same as the case for two digits.

Example - three digits:

```
counter = 0;
options = generate_all_combinations_for_k_digits_in_order(2) //for the 3 digit case.
//options = [10, 11, 12, ..., 20, 21, ..., 91, 92, ..., 99]
for (int i = 0; i < number_of_digits - 1; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < options.length; j++)
    {
        print_9_in_position_i_of_number_j(i,j);
        counter++;
        if (counter == x)
            break; // End the loop somehow... 
    }
}
```

Comment: Well, that's basically the brute-force approach. You loop over the complete range of possible numbers and test each against the pattern.

Comment: @Sebi - no it is not. Every number that you get to in this idea is an answer that needs to be printed out. Brute force means going over ALL 3 digit number and checking whether or not *9* fits them. Consider, for the two digit case, any of the following: `10,11,18,20,..28, ..,80, .. 88`. Does this idea iterate over them?

Comment: So it seems I don't understand your code. Where is the pattern I need to search for like \*923\*? Also, what is this magic `generate_all_combinations_for_k_digits(2)` function doing and how does it work?

Comment: What are the "additional digits"/options for k=4 when the pattern is "*9*"? Does it include "191"? If not, when does "1991" appear in the output? If it does include "191", how does "1991" not appear twice? Also: how is the output sorted?

Comment: @Sebi - the functions gives you all permutations of k digits (sorted). That is not very hard to do I think.

Comment: @PaulHankin - Yes, it should include `191`. Yes, my example will print out `1991` twice - which it shouldn't. I did not think of these cases. You could have a list of generated numbers and check there - though this would slow down the process. It is order if `generate_all_combinations_for_k_digits(3)` returns an ordered list.

Comment: @PaulHankin - edited to `generate_all_combinations_for_k_digits_in_order(2)` for clarity.

Comment: OK, but I still don't see how it's sorted. Won't numbers that start with "9" appear first? Surely the first number in the case k=3 and pattern="\*9\*" should be "009" (or 109 if you're requiring the numbers to be exactly 3 digits long).

Comment: @PaulHankin - `109` should be the first number, I agree. You get back the list of two digit numbers (`10,11,12..,99`), and start inserting the `9` in the different locations. Again, need to remove duplications...

Comment: @shapiroyaacov If I understand right, you start by going through the list inserting '9' at the end. The first few numbers are 109, 119, 129, ..., 209, 219, ..., 989, 999. Then you go through the list again, inserting 9 one from the end. 190, 191, 192, etc. But while each pass is sorted, the overall output is not sorted -- 999 comes before 190 for example.

Comment: And sorry to keep pointing out problems, but it looks like 900, 901, ..., 908 don't appear in the output.

Comment: @PaulHankin - you have excellent points to point out - don't be sorry in the slightest. Apparently my bright idea has some issues... Though I still think it's a good place to start from.

Comment: @PaulHankin , Yaacov what do you think of my answer?

Answer (score 1):

Here's the pattern:

```
1009
  ^-- 0-8
1090
   ^-- 0-8

1109
  ^-- 0-8
1190
   ^-- 0-8
 ...
1209
 ^-- 2-8 and the rightmost two digit pattern repeats till 1900
1900
  01-99 this is different
 --------------------------------------------------------------
^-- 2-8 Now the whole previous structure repeats for each thousand until 9000

9000
 ^-- 001-999
```

We can formulate a recursion for `n < 10^m and n has m digits`:

```
f(n = 10^m - 1)
   => 9*10^(m-1) + 1..10^(m-2)-1  // that's like the 9000 + (001..999)
   => 8*10^(m-1) + f(n-1)         // now for each leftmost digit down to 1, 
   => ...                         // we append all the results from f(n-1)
   => 1*10^(m-1) + f(n-1)
```

Ruby code:

```rb
def f m    
  if m == 1
   return [9]
  end

  result = []

  ((10**m).to_i - 1).downto(9 * 10**(m-1).to_i).each do |i|
    result << i
  end

  temp = 10**(m-1)

  8.downto(0).each do |i|
    f(m-1).each do |j|
      result << (i * temp + j)
    end
  end

  result
end
```

Results:

```
ruby 2.3.1p112 (2016-04-26 revision 54768) [x86_64-linux]

=> :f
 > f 3
=> [999, 998, 997, 996, 995, 994, 993, 992, 991, 990, 989, 988, 987, 986, 985, 984, 983
   , 982, 981, 980, 979, 978, 977, 976, 975, 974, 973, 972, 971, 970, 969, 968, 967, 966
   , 965, 964, 963, 962, 961, 960, 959, 958, 957, 956, 955, 954, 953, 952, 951, 950, 949
   , 948, 947, 946, 945, 944, 943, 942, 941, 940, 939, 938, 937, 936, 935, 934, 933, 932
   , 931, 930, 929, 928, 927, 926, 925, 924, 923, 922, 921, 920, 919, 918, 917, 916, 915
   , 914, 913, 912, 911, 910, 909, 908, 907, 906, 905, 904, 903, 902, 901, 900, 899, 898
   , 897, 896, 895, 894, 893, 892, 891, 890, 889, 879, 869, 859, 849, 839, 829, 819, 809
   , 799, 798, 797, 796, 795, 794, 793, 792, 791, 790, 789, 779, 769, 759, 749, 739, 729
   , 719, 709, 699, 698, 697, 696, 695, 694, 693, 692, 691, 690, 689, 679, 669, 659, 649
   , 639, 629, 619, 609, 599, 598, 597, 596, 595, 594, 593, 592, 591, 590, 589, 579, 569
   , 559, 549, 539, 529, 519, 509, 499, 498, 497, 496, 495, 494, 493, 492, 491, 490, 489
   , 479, 469, 459, 449, 439, 429, 419, 409, 399, 398, 397, 396, 395, 394, 393, 392, 391
   , 390, 389, 379, 369, 359, 349, 339, 329, 319, 309, 299, 298, 297, 296, 295, 294, 293
   , 292, 291, 290, 289, 279, 269, 259, 249, 239, 229, 219, 209, 199, 198, 197, 196, 195
   , 194, 193, 192, 191, 190, 189, 179, 169, 159, 149, 139, 129, 119, 109, 99, 98, 97
   , 96, 95, 94, 93, 92, 91, 90, 89, 79, 69, 59, 49, 39, 29, 19, 9]
 > f(4).length
=> 3439
```

Comment: Works great for `9` and is by far the best answer so far, but it's not so easy to generate the sorted order if `9` is replaced by something else no?

Comment: @PaulHankin Yea, I was actually going to begin the answer with, "you got lucky that 9 is the fixed term..." lol

Comment: your answer inspired me to have a go myself. I think I managed to generalize your code so that it works no matter the pattern -- whether a different digit from 9 or with multiple digits.

Comment: Well, 9 is only an example in my question. It can be any integer number as long as it is within the search range. So it could also be 12345 and similar.

Comment: @Sebi oh, I misunderstood the question. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1):

My attempt at a "next lexicographic" algorithm for a fixed length string.

JavaScript code:

```js
function f(str,pat){
  if (str[0] == 0 
   || isNaN(Number(str))
   || isNaN(Number(pat))
   || str.length == pat.length 
   || str == String(Math.pow(10,str.length - pat.length) - 1 + pat) ){
    return str;
  }

  var AP = "",
      i = 0;

  while (!AP.match(pat) && i < str.length){
    AP += str[i++];
  }

  // if there are digits to the right of the pattern
  if (AP.length < str.length){

    // increment the string if the pattern won't break
    if (String(Number(str) + 1).match(pat)){
      return Number(str) + 1;

    // otherwise, find first number that may be incremented
    } else {
      var i = str.length - pat.length - 1
            + (pat.match(/^9+/) ? pat.match(/9+/)[0].length : 0)

      while (str[i] == 9 && i-- >= 0){
      }

      // increment at i, move pattern to the right, set zeros in between
      return (Number(str.substr(0,i + 1)) + 1) 
           * Math.pow(10,str.length - pat.length) 
           + Number(pat)
    }

  // if the pattern is all the way on the right 
  } else {

    // find rightmost placement for the pattern along an adjacent
    // match where the string could be incremented
    i = 1;

    for (;i<pat.length; i++){
      var j = str.length - pat.length - i,
          patShifted = Number(pat) * Math.pow(10,i);

      if (str.substr(j,i) == pat.substr(0,i) 
       && patShifted > Number(str.substr(j))){

        return Number(str.substr(0,j) + String(patShifted));
      }
    }

    // if no left-shifted placement was found
    return (Number(str.substr(0,str.length - pat.length)) + 1)
          * Math.pow(10,pat.length) + Number(pat);
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is a solution. I also noticed yesterday that one can always increment A as long as A doesn't match parts of P. In that case, one must continue with B till it is exhausted. You describe it here in a more formal way :-)

Comment: I don't quite follow this algorithm -- for example I think `P` is the pattern to be matched, but then I don't see what "set (P) to zeros" can mean. Although I don't fully understand what you're doing, I'm suspicious that it doesn't mention what happens when P appears in multiple places in the string, I'm going to guess it doesn't generate results in lex order because of this. Can you write code for it? Even naive and inefficient code would suffice to check its correctness.

Comment: @PaulHankin thanks for weighing in. I think multiple occurrences would imply my second case - where P (is now after an edit) the leftmost appearance of the pattern. Can you think of a counterexample?

Comment: @גלעדברקן sorry, but I don't understand well enough the explanation of your algorithm. Can you convert it into code?

Comment: @PaulHankin added code, it seems a bit lengthy and complex and I'm not even sure if the algorithm is sound.